# Question about ASP.NET Code Behind model

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I am thinking about the asp.net 2.0 code behind model.

After I drag a button onto my *Default.aspx* page, I got the following declaration in my *Default.aspx.designer.cs* file:

```
public partial class _Default {

    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;

    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1;
}
```

And now it's OK for me to write the following code in *Default.aspx.cs* file:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Text = "clicked!";
}
```

But I am wondering, what I got is nothing but a **declaration** of Button1 variable of Button type, it hasn't been **instanciated**, how could this code run without trigging a **Null Reference Exception**?

I think there must exist some code like this somewhere:

```
Button1 = new Button();
```

But where is this code? When is this code executed? Who executes it?

Many thanks...

### Update - 1 - 21:17 12/15/2010

I found 2 auto-generated file in a mysterious location *C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\edd9f4a1\7f113408*, they are:

```
App_Web_x_swwj6s.1.cs
App_Web_x_swwj6s.0.cs
```

I found code like below in the App_Web_x_swwj6s.0.cs file:

```
        private global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button @__BuildControlButton1()
         {
            global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button @__ctrl;                
            @__ctrl = new global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button();
            //....
            this.Button1 = @__ctrl;
            return @__ctrl;
          }
```

And this method is invoked in the below code:

```
private global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm @__BuildControlform1()
{
  //....
  global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button @__ctrl1;

  @__ctrl1 = this.@__BuildControlButton1();
  //......
}
```

And finally the above code is invoked in the following method:

```
protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
```

So I believed that the **FrameworkInitialize()** method is the one who did the dirty job of bind the control *reference* to a control *instance*.

To prove this, I intentionally wrote the following code in my code-behind file:

```
protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
{
    this.Button1 = null;
}
```

I hope there would be a Null Reference Exception when I click the button, but strange enough, the whole web site run smoothly.

Is it true that all the controls I declared in the aspx file are created with the FrameworkInitialize() method? Why there's no Null Reference Exception in the above scenario?

Many thanks again.

### Update - 2 - 21:43 12/15/2010

I think I may find the explanation, I checked the final page class generated by ASP.NET with .NET reflector. Its deriving relation is like this:

**default_aspx** class (The ultimate class representing the page)<--- **_Default** class (the code behind class) <--- System.Web.UI.Page

And in the default_aspx class, I found this:

```
protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
{
    base.FrameworkInitialize();  // Button1=null is executed here.
    this.__BuildControlTree(this); // Here Button1 is STILL set to an instance.
    base.AddWrappedFileDependencies(__fileDependencies);
    base.Request.ValidateInput();
}
```

So, this could explain why my intention to set the Button1 to null failed.

**Now, my question is, does the FrameworkInitialize() method has to be called at the very beginning of a page's life cycle so that we could use the control on the page afterwards.**

### Update - 3 - 3:45 PM 12/16/2010

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479007.aspx):

> Once the HTTP page handler class is
>   fully identified, the ASP.NET run time
>   calls the handler's ProcessRequest
>   method to process the request.
>   Normally, there is no need to change
>   the implementation of the method as it
>   is provided by the Page class.
>
> This implementation begins by calling
>   the method FrameworkInitialize, which
>   builds the controls tree for the page.
>   The method is a protected and virtual
>   member of the TemplateControl
>   class—the class from which Page itself
>   derives. Any dynamically generated
>   handler for an .aspx resource
>   overrides FrameworkInitialize. In this
>   method, the whole control tree for the
>   page is built.

### A bounty is started for your precious comments. :)

Comment: Since the "answer" was deleted but I think the link within it might still have relevant information to someone viewing this question: http://peterkellner.net/2006/07/12/how-things-work-aspnet-20-codebehind/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what exactly do you want to get answers to now... to me it looks like you're answering most of your questions your self? :)

Regarding the `FrameworkInitialize` its easiest if you fire up Reflector and look at the code. Code is law! :) In here you'll see that `System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.FrameworkInitialize()`
 will call a internal method named `System.Web.Compilation.BuildResultNoCompileTemplateControlFrameworkInitialize(TemplateControl)`which is doing the actual initialization of your control tree. This means that overriding `FrameworkInitialize()` and setting your `Button1` to null doesn't have any effect, since that code will end up being run BEFORE the control tree is initialized.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am just not sure about my answer. :) So a bounty is started for any relevant comments.

Answer (score 3):

The page and its controls (including your button in this case) are instantiated by the webforms "view engine" before the OnLoad, etc events are fired.

Otherwise, you'd have to have an ISAPI filter or similar device intercept requests and create the page object and its controls before *any* events were fired. This is what the ASP.NET ISAPI DLL does, I think.

I haven't tried this, but you may be able to set a break point in the page's constructor to see the `::Controls[]` list before anything is created, which I would expect to be empty (but the page life cycle link I've provided below will have a better explanation).

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) or [this one](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020102.htm).

Comment: Thanks. Based on your reply and Joel Etherton's, now I know where the instanciation code is. But still not sure when that code is executed.

Comment: When you say `when that code is executed`, are you referring to the page/control instantiation or the event handler?

Comment: This whole process is more clear when you look at ASP.NET MVC. A few layers of abstraction are removed, allowing you to get more intimate with the request/instantiate/render/reply process. (Not saying MVC is better/worse than webforms - it's just a more transparent process.)