# Why should our eventhandler or member variables are declared protected in asp.net codebehind

Tags: asp.net

Why should our eventhandler or member variables are declared protected in asp.net codebehind?

This works.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdlOther.Checked)
        pnlOther.Visible = true;
    else
        pnlOther.Visible = false;
}
```

But this not,

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdlOther.Checked)
        pnlOther.Visible = true;
    else
        pnlOther.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question about ASP.NET Code Behind model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441066/question-about-asp-net-code-behind-model)

Answer (score 3):

See [Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> Classes and structs can be restricted so that only the program or
>   namespace they are declared in may use them. Class members can be
>   restricted so that only derived classes can use them, or restricted so
>   that only classes within the current namespace or program can use
>   them. Access modifiers are keywords added to the class, struct, or
>   member declaration to specify these restrictions. Those keywords are
>   public, private, protected, and internal.

Looking at two of the levels, we can get their definitions:

> - Private members are accessible only within the body of the class or
>     the struct in which they are declared
> - A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived
>     classes.

Example from the default.aspx page I'm working on now:

```
<%@ Page Title="Store  Price Management - Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

and the corresponding .cs file:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  // /stuff here
}
```

If you look at the aspx page you'll see that the aspx page inherits (is derived from) the class defined in the .cs file.

Therefore, in order to have the Default.aspx (which inherits class _Default) access a member, it must be marked with *at least* protected access level.  public works as well.

Comment: No even private doesnt work when putting with <script runat="server">